# iOS-chart: remove DataSet label and color indicator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

While drawing a line chart I need the entire canvas to be clean, I have figured out how to clean most of the default graphics like the grid background, grid itself, rightLabels, etc.

But I have not been able to get rid of the *DataSet* label and line color indicator.

[image: Cleaned Graph]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the *label* and keep the color indicator pass blank `""` to label the value of `dataSet` like:

> let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: chartData, label: "")

But in case you want to drop both the color indicator and label you will have to update the `legend` of the `chartView` like:

> chartView.legendRenderer.legend?.enabled = false.

Let me know if you need all settings that I have updated to achieve presented chart representation.